# Beats Music not working as Fluid app

Tags: macos, mac, safari, fluid

I'm trying to set up Beats Music as a Fluid app so it's not buried in a bunch of browser tabs.

For some reason, on my laptop, I can get it to load, but no songs play (checking the error console shows some 404s and some 'undefined' javascript errors).

On my home Mac Pro, I was able to set this up with no problem at all, so I know it can be done. Also, [this tweet conversation](https://twitter.com/kicksopenminds/status/428656666310348800) proves it can be done too.

Initially I thought it was because in Safari on my laptop, I'm running Ghostery, AdBlock, and Click2Flash extensions. However, I've disabled those individually, and even disabled extensions all together, but I still can't get music to play.

Any other ideas? I'm at a loss as to what might be causing this Fluid to be prohibiting Beats to play music.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this. Seems like it was a Click2Flash problem.

I deleted Click2Flash from Safari, but that still didn't help Beats within a Fluid App.

In the Beats Fluid app, I [visited a page](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativecloud/web.html) that I knew had a Flash element on it. Even though Click2Flash was deleted from Safari, it was still blocking this element. So I clicked the gear in the top left corner, went to the Settings, and deleted the plugin that way.

After doing that, the Beats Fluid app started playing music! I reinstalled Beats in Safari, added listen.beatsmusic.com to the whitelist, and now it's playing everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out I had Flash installed at a browser level only. I downloaded and installed the [Flash Player system plug-in](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and now Beats Music works as a Fluid app.